# Android - Crashing on setContentView() prior to v24 API

Tags: android, layout, view, crash

When I run my app on the emulator with version 27 & 28 APIs, everything works for me. However, as soon as I try to go to a lower level API, I get error messages regarding the setContentView() method in my custom Activity.java class.

Here is the stack trace:

```
2018-12-06 15:37:59.166 9426-9426/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.mplexvr.ribbonracker, PID: 9426
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mplexvr.ribbonracker/com.mplexvr.ribbonracker.RibbonRackerActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0b0000
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0b0000
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:190)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:766)
    at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.setIcon(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:322)
    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setIcon(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:737)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setDefaultIcon(PhoneWindow.java:1737)
    at android.app.Activity.initWindowDecorActionBar(Activity.java:2400)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2415)
    at com.mplexvr.ribbonracker.RibbonRackerActivity.onCreate(RibbonRackerActivity.java:46)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

I tried to run this app on both a phone and emulator with a version 24 api, and nothing works. My activity_main.xml that the onCreate() method tries to call just contains two fragments that are modified in the onCreate() method. Here is a snippet of code from that:

```
/* This code runs perfectly fine on the version 28 and 27 api on the emulator*/
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    images = new ArrayList<>();
    imageNames = new ArrayList<>();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.v(TAG, "I got in onCreate");


    //Create the fragment for the ranking and add it to the current view
    // Get references to the TitleFragment and to the QuotesFragment containers
    mRibbonFrameLayout = findViewById(R.id.ribbon_fragment_container);
    mChecklistFrameLayout = findViewById(R.id.checkbox_fragment_container);

    ...
}
```

I tried looking this problem up, but nothing I found has solved this problem - at least publicly.

**UPDATE** Solved within 5 minutes when I figured out that a folder had a version of 26, which would limit on using that version.

Comment: It says it can't find a Drawable resource, which probably means you're referencing some Drawable that's inside `drawable-v24`.

Comment: Check your R file to see which resources has value 0x7f0b0000, and then figure out from there.

Comment: Yea, it was something completely unexpected - it had the form of "minimap-v26" and I needed to delete that to make it general to all. Ah, I was dealing with this for a while, thanks guys.